# Как сделать полный снапшот сервера?

Tags: веб-сервер, сервер

Есть проблема - нужно сменить серверное оборудование, а именно старый сервер заменить на новый. Как можно сделать полный снапшот старого сервера и перенести его на новый сервер (с настройками Apache, PHP, MySQL и так далее)? Или в любом случае придется заново установить операционную систему на новый сервер? Очень жду Вашей помощи...

Comment: Уточните, для начала, - сервер на голом сервере? Или на сервере?Переведу: серверная операционная система установлена напрямую на железо или на виртуальную машину?ЗЫ Определитесь, что же Вы понимаете под термином "сервер". А то у меня вот сервер на ADSL-модеме... А вы рискуете получить ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ответ типа "Как перевезти web-сервер? Нет ничего проще! Ставите его в багажник и перевозите."...

Comment: что за сервер ? имеете ли вы к серверам физический доступ ? можно скопировать с помощью dd. или tar и установить заново загрузчик.

Comment: Сервер физический, не виртуальный...

Answer (score 1):

Перенос системы делается копированием всех корневых папок папок, кроме: /boot, /proc, /tmpТакже надо игнорировать из папки /etc такие данные как настройка сети и обязательно проигнорировать файл fstab и mtab

Упаковку надо делать со всеми остановленными службами

Вот буквально несколько дней назад переносил людям сервер.Упаковывал папки находясь в корне ОС Дебиан так:tar czf /home/etc.tar.gz etctar czf /home/lib.tar.gz libtar czf /home/lib32.tar.gz lib32tar czf /home/opt.tar.gz opttar czf /home/root.tar.gz roottar czf /home/srv.tar.gz srvtar czf /home/usr.tar.gz usrtar czf /home/var.tar.gz var

Распаковывал на новом серваке, все в папке /hometar xzf etc.tar.gz и т.д

Помните, что все надо делать в системе восстановления.Из папки etc копировать все осторожно, что содержит IP адреса и MAC адреса, а также старую разметку дисков НЕ НУЖНО.

Желаю удачи в переносе ОС

Answer (score 0):

Вам в помощь [Clonzilla](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla) 
Здесь есть статьи с примерами [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%5Bclonezilla%5D&target_type=posts)

Comment: Я так уже переводил несколько серверов с одного железа на другое.

Answer (score 0):

use zfs luke........